# Extracting Keyword from an image using R

Tags: r, pdf, ocr, tesseract, keyword

Let's suppose I have a pdf file which contains invoice. So,this is an image in a pdf file. Now, if I want to extract the keyword 'total', how can I do that?

So far, I have come up with the following code below:

```
curl::curl_download("https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf", "wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf")
orig <- pdftools::pdf_text("wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf")
# Render pdf to png image
img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert("wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf", format = 'tiff', pages = 1, dpi = 400)
# Extract text from png image
text <- ocr(img_file)
unlink(img_file)
cat(text)
```

The above code helps to extract text from the image, however, it excludes the text present in the tabular form. Also, if I want to just extract 'Invoice Number' and 'Total Due $93.50', how is it achievable using R? I would be really thankful if someone could help me in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabulizer` package

```
library(tabulizer)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

out <- extract_tables( "https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf")

out = as.data.table(out)
out %>% filter(V1=='Invoice Number' | V1=='Total Due')

              V1       V2
1 Invoice Number INV-3337
2      Total Due   $93.50
```

Comment: This answer is helpful in the current scenario. What if the invoice number and Total Due are not present in the table, but merely as a text in the form of an image in a pdf file. How will we then be able to extract the keywords?